# No sound card on Ubuntu 18

Tags: soundcard

Colleagues,

I am not sure but think an update caused this problem. I have "dummy Sound output" (basically no audio in the PC) and tried several commands on the posts with no luck.
This is the system I have (Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS)

- Processor : Intel core i5-8400 CPU @ 2.8 GHz x 6
- Graphics : Intel HD Graphics (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)
- GNOME : 3.28.2
- OS : 64 bits

Here are some commands

#### lshw -C multimedia

```
santi@santi-desktop:~$ sudo lshw -C multimedia  
[sudo] contraseña para santi:  
  *-multimedia              
       descripción: Audio device  
       producto: Intel Corporation  
       fabricante: Intel Corporation  
       id físico: 1f.3  
       información del bus: pci@0000:00:1f.3  
       versión: 10  
       anchura: 64 bits  
       reloj: 33MHz  
       capacidades: pm msi bus_master cap_list  
       configuración: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32  
       recursos: irq:128 memoria:a1210000-a1213fff memoria:a1000000-a10fffff
```

#### lshw -short

```
santi@santi-desktop:~$ sudo lshw -short

*ruta H/W       Dispositivo  Clase          Descripción**

  system         To Be Filled By O.E.M. (To Be Filled   
/0                          bus            H310M-HDV  
/0/0                        memory         64KiB BIOS  
/0/9                        memory         8GiB Memoria de sistema  
/0/9/0                      memory         8GiB DIMM DDR4 Síncrono 2400 MHz   (0,
/0/9/1                      memory         DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Ms  
/0/12                       memory         384KiB L1 caché  
/0/13                       memory         1536KiB L2 caché  
/0/14                       memory         9MiB L3 caché  
/0/15                       processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8400 CPU @ 2.80G  
/0/100                      bridge         Intel Corporation  
/0/100/2                    display        Intel Corporation  
/0/100/12                   generic        Intel Corporation  
/0/100/14                   bus            Intel Corporation  
/0/100/14/0    usb1         bus            xHCI Host Controller  
/0/100/14/0/2               input          Dell USB Keyboard  
/0/100/14/0/7               input          2.4G Keyboard Mouse  
/0/100/14/1    usb2         bus            xHCI Host Controller  
/0/100/14.2                 memory         RAM memory  
/0/100/16                   communication  Intel Corporation  
/0/100/17                   storage        Intel Corporation  
/0/100/1d                   bridge         Intel Corporation  
/0/100/1d/0    enp1s0       network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit  
/0/100/1f                   bridge         Intel Corporation  
/0/100/1f.3                 multimedia     Intel Corporation  
/0/100/1f.4                 bus            Intel Corporation  
/0/100/1f.5                 bus            Intel Corporation  
/0/1           scsi1        storage        
/0/1/0.0.0     /dev/sda     disk           1TB WDC WD10EZEX-08W  
/0/1/0.0.0/1   /dev/sda1    volume         511MiB Windows FAT volumen  
/0/1/0.0.0/2   /dev/sda2    volume         931GiB partición EXT4
```

#### lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio

```
santi@santi-desktop:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio  
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a348] (rev 10)  
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:288a]  
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```

#### uname -r

```
santi@santi-desktop:~$ uname -r  
4.15.0-42-generic
```

#### alsamixer

```
santi@santi-desktop:~$ alsamixer  
no se puede abrir el mezclador: No existe el archivo o el directorio  
(can not open the mixer: Does not exist the file or directory)  

santi@santi-desktop:~$
```

I have an ASRock mother H310M-HDV and it says 7.1CH HD Audio(Realtek ALC887 Audio Codec) and btw could not find this codec in realtek

Can anyone help me?